# Is Map Available Offline in Android also available for applications?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

There is function in the new Google Maps Android app to make an area of the map available for offline viewing, is there a way to have applications in android be able to do this? or to cache part the map in the SDCard?

Answer (score 2):

v2 of google maps caches tiles automatically when you read them which is why you have to use the write external storage permission

`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Allows the API to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area.`

but you cannot manage them and the cache can be cleared